# What is the guru parampara of varkari sect?

Tags: vishnu

Varkari sect is Vaishnava community in Maharashtra which serves Panduranga(incarnation of Shri hari) in Pandharpur.

Since every Vaishnava tradition traces its Guru parampara back to Shriman Narayana, what is varkari guruparampara